# Applying Perlin noise shader just to some objects within a mesh

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I would like to modify one object within a mesh using perlin noise. How I am doing this right now...

1. I am creating the objects and adding them to a 3d object...

   ```
    spheres = new THREE.Object3D();
    for ( var i = 0; i < 40; i ++ ) {
        var ball = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(20,20,20), material);
        ball.position.x = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
        ball.position.y = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
        ball.position.z = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
        spheres.add(ball);
   }
   scene.add(spheres);
   ```
2. I am using a shader material...

   ```
   material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
     uniforms: { 
   time: { 
       type: "f", 
       value: 0.0 
   },
   noisemax: { 
       type: "f", 
       value: 100.0 
   },
   transparent: true

   },
   vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
   fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
   });
   ```

The shader material works on all 40 balls no problem. What I would like to do is change the shader say for `spheres.children[0]`. Is it possible to change the perlin noise values (noiseMax) for one object or does it by nature effect the material for all objects using the material?

Comment: That is a good question. Have you tried it? I too have been playing with shaders over the past few days and have started a post about it [here](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) if your interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

The easy way is to create and use a separate ShaderMaterial for each item that differs, and you can set its uniform easily. e.g.

```
var firstMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: { noisemax: { type: 'f', value: 3}}
});

var secondMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: { noisemax: { type: 'f', value: 10}}
});

var firstBall = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(20,20,20), firstMaterial);
var secondBall = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(20,20,20), secondMaterial);

// or in your case
spheres.children[0].material = secondMaterial;
```

Alternatively and probably preferably for your situation (at least from a performance standpoint) is that you should change noisemax to an **attribute**, that way you can have a separate value per object.

You will have to remember that attributes are per vertex, so you'll need to duplicate the values for all vertices belonging to each object. This will complicate things a little bit.

Edit: To reduce memory usage, you can use [THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry with THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_billboards)

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I thought I tried this exactly and it didnt work. Ill try again and get back to you otherwise Ill try the attribute way.

Comment: Brendan any suggested reading on attributes vs multiple materials?